# Приложение вылетает android-toast Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

При нажатии на кнопку должно выводиться уведомление с текстом и картинкой. 
Однако при нажатии приложение просто появляется черный экран и приложение вылетает. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

```
    ...
    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_notice)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, R.string.learnkotlin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0)
        val toastContainer = toast.view as LinearLayout
        val learnImage = ImageView(this)
        learnImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.kotlin_logo)
        toastContainer.addView(learnImage, 0)
        toast.show()
    }
    ...
```

Вот ошибки из logcat:

```
2022-03-20 19:16:12.491 12496-12496/com.example.notification_kotlin E/Toast: setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
2022-03-20 19:16:12.506 12496-12496/com.example.notification_kotlin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.notification_kotlin, PID: 12496
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.LinearLayout
        at com.example.notification_kotlin.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:20)
        at com.example.notification_kotlin.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$gh0bxtkEy_cl8jl923-C5Pnh0sg(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.notification_kotlin.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: если приложение вылетает, значит должен быть приложен лог с текстом ошибки к вопросу, так сложно сказать где именно у вас проблема.

Comment: Ошибки из logcat добавил

Comment: ошибка судя по всему показывает на эту строку - `val toastContainer = toast.view as LinearLayout` вы я так понимаю хотите сделать внизу всплывающее сообщение с картинкой или что?

Comment: Да, все верно, но я пробовал поменять положение (указывал CENTER, TOP), но все равно те же ошибки

Comment: `toast.view`  в тот момент `null`. Вероятнее всего интерфейс еще не создан.

Comment: Что в этом случае можно сделать?

Comment: Лучше не пытаться менять стандартный Toast, а создавать его со своим интерфейсом. Пример старый, но идея понятна: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571917/adding-image-to-toast

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Но у нас по заданию нужно именно стандартный Toast использовать